# How to set a NOT NULL column into NULL in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, null

I'm new to PostgreSQL and that is why I'm asking this question. I have a table `app_client_users` and a column named `client_id`. Initially I set it as `NOT NULL` and now I would like to change it to allow NULL. I've tried

```
alter table app_client_users alter column client_id int  NULL ;
```

and

```
alter table app_client_users alter column client_id   NULL ;
```

which is not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please be aware that `psql` is a client to PostgreSQL, not a nickname of the latter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply drop `NOT NULL`

```
ALTER TABLE app_client_users ALTER COLUMN client_id DROP NOT NULL;
```